# xDB Data Migration tool fails

Tags: xdb, mongodb, migration

I'm trying to migrate the analytics data from Sitecore 8.2.4 to 9.0.2. The tool worked about 12 hours and failed with the following message:

> 10152 19:08:25 ERROR [Data Exchange] An error occurred when trying to add the entity to the xConnect client. (thread id: 4, pipeline: Process Single Interaction from MongoDB Pipeline, pipeline step: Add Interaction Model to xConnect Batch, pipeline step identifier: f5fdb6f1-3557-461e-a75c-3cd9179077fe, entity model internal description: e298e777-8a40-4fb5-99fd-453560881695)
>
> 10152 19:08:25 ERROR [Data Exchange] Exception while submitting batch to xConnect. (thread id: 4, pipeline: Process Single Interaction from MongoDB Pipeline, pipeline step: Add Interaction Model to xConnect Batch, pipeline step identifier: f5fdb6f1-3557-461e-a75c-3cd9179077fe)
>   10152 19:08:25 ERROR [Data Exchange] One or more errors occurred. (thread id: 4, pipeline: Process Single Interaction from MongoDB Pipeline, pipeline step: Add Interaction Model to xConnect Batch, pipeline step identifier: f5fdb6f1-3557-461e-a75c-3cd9179077fe)
>
> 10152 19:08:25 ERROR [Data Exchange] START AGGREGATE EXCEPTION (thread id: 4, pipeline: Process Single Interaction from MongoDB Pipeline, pipeline step: Add Interaction Model to xConnect Batch, pipeline step identifier: f5fdb6f1-3557-461e-a75c-3cd9179077fe, ID: 1, HResult: -2146233088)
>   ---- An error occurred when trying to add the entity to the xConnect client. (thread id: 4, pipeline: Process Single Interaction from MongoDB Pipeline, pipeline step: Add Interaction Model to xConnect Batch, pipeline step identifier: f5fdb6f1-3557-461e-a75c-3cd9179077fe, entity model internal description: e298e777-8a40-4fb5-99fd-453560881695)
>
> ---- ---- An error occurred when trying to add the entity to the xConnect client. (thread id: 4, pipeline: Process Single Interaction from MongoDB Pipeline, pipeline step: Add Interaction Model to xConnect Batch, pipeline step identifier: f5fdb6f1-3557-461e-a75c-3cd9179077fe, entity model internal description: e298e777-8a40-4fb5-99fd-453560881695)
>   Operation #2, ReferenceNotFound, Contact, Emails (thread id: 4, pipeline: Process Single Interaction from MongoDB Pipeline, pipeline step: Add Interaction Model to xConnect Batch, pipeline step identifier: f5fdb6f1-3557-461e-a75c-3cd9179077fe)
>   ---- ---- An error occurred when trying to add the entity to the xConnect client. (thread id: 4, pipeline: Process Single Interaction from MongoDB Pipeline, pipeline step: Add Interaction Model to xConnect Batch, pipeline step identifier: f5fdb6f1-3557-461e-a75c-3cd9179077fe, entity model internal description: e298e777-8a40-4fb5-99fd-453560881695)
>   Operation #3, ReferenceNotFound, Contact, Personal (thread id: 4, pipeline: Process Single Interaction from MongoDB Pipeline, pipeline step: Add Interaction Model to xConnect Batch, pipeline step identifier: f5fdb6f1-3557-461e-a75c-3cd9179077fe)
>   ---- ---- An error occurred when trying to add the entity to the xConnect client. (thread id: 4, pipeline: Process Single Interaction from MongoDB Pipeline, pipeline step: Add Interaction Model to xConnect Batch, pipeline step identifier: f5fdb6f1-3557-461e-a75c-3cd9179077fe, entity model internal description: e298e777-8a40-4fb5-99fd-453560881695)
>   Operation #4, ReferenceNotFound, Contact, PhoneNumbers (thread id: 4, pipeline: Process Single Interaction from MongoDB Pipeline, pipeline step: Add Interaction Model to xConnect Batch, pipeline step identifier: f5fdb6f1-3557-461e-a75c-3cd9179077fe)
>   ...
>   END AGGREGATE EXCEPTION (thread id: 4, pipeline: Process Single Interaction from MongoDB Pipeline, pipeline step: Add Interaction Model to xConnect Batch, pipeline step identifier: f5fdb6f1-3557-461e-a75c-3cd9179077fe, ID: 2, HResult: -2146233088)

What is the reason of the issue and how I can deal with it? I guess it should skip the contact in question and continue, but it aborts the execution at all.

Comment: Anything in the xconnect site logs?

Comment: Nothing useful, it just says that xConnect started

Comment: As one of the option to skip failed batch is enable checkbox field "Do Not Close All Threads On Exception" on "Iterate MongoDB Contacts and Run Pipelines" pipeline step

Comment: Yes, I did it but it did not help. If a critical error occurred it interrupts the whole process.

Answer (score 1):

I've received the same error before. After reaching out to SC Support about it, they told us to ensure that we have no data in the Connect Shard databases. This applies if you are not running it in "Resume mode."

To the issue of removing the xConnect data, I've had success with the [ADM](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwjylvXx-M3hAhUFSq0KHbKfCkQQFjAAegQIAxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmarketplace.sitecore.net%2FModules%2FAnalytics_Database_Manager.aspx&usg=AOvVaw1RN_xm4WQlVqOxXwIima9m) module (version 4.0.0 or 4.0.1 for 9.0.x and 9.x, respectively.) One must remove the three default "Data Remover Configurators" to delete all of the data, however.